# How to take screenshot of the scene in cocos2dx 3.3?

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I Am developing a game and i want to take scene screen shot..How it possible in cocos2dx 3.3?Please tell me

My Code is Given Below

```
    CCSize screenSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    CCRenderTexture * tex = CCRenderTexture::create(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
    tex->setPosition(ccp(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2));

    tex->begin();
    this->getParent()->visit();
    tex->end();

    tex->saveToFile("Image_Save.png", kCCImageFormatPNG);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Replace

```
tex->saveToFile("Image_Save.png", Image::Format::PNG);
```

Instead of

```
tex->saveToFile("Image_Save.png", kCCImageFormatPNG);
```

It might be surely help you

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
utils::captureScreen( CC_CALLBACK_2(GameScene::afterCaptured, this), "screenshot.png");

//callback function

void GameScene::afterCaptured(bool succeed, const std::string &outputFile)
{    
    if (succeed) {
        log(" screen shot%s", outputFile.c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: Which file this code belongs too. I have sharing function in Helper classs.